# Flacards package - renewcommand with variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, flashcards

I have a problem with the `flacards` package. I'm trying to make playing cards, where the frame of different cards are colored differently. Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,frontgrid]{flacards}
\usepackage{aurical}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,shadows,decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shapes.geometric,patterns}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\fboxsep=0mm

\renewcommand{\frfoot}{\footnotesize\thecardno\hskip3pt\smallskip} % change layout for left foot on front
\renewcommand{\brfoot}{}

%Group Colors

\definecolor{griff}{RGB}{224, 57, 35}
\definecolor{slyth}{RGB}{45, 205, 109}

%Command for Card Title:
\renewcommand{\fchead}[1]{\textbf{\Huge{#1}}}

%BACKGROUND

\renewcommand{\flhead}[1]{\texttransparent{0.4} %Background Transparency
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node  at (3.18,-4.64) {
   \includegraphics[width=63.47mm, height=92.477mm]{pics/parch4.jpg}
};%
\end{tikzpicture}}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill[{black}, even odd rule]

(-0.138,-9.24) rectangle ++(63.47mm,92.477mm)
(-0.138 + 0.175,-9.24+0.175) rectangle ++(60mm,89mm);
\end{tikzpicture}}
}

\begin{document}

\Fontskrivan
\pagesetup{3}{3} % 3x3 cards

\card{
\fchead{Test}\\
Test}{Empty}

\end{document}
```

Now, If I renew the command `\flhead` to make it dependent to a variable #1, it seems not to work, since the predefined macro `\card` prints the `\flhead` command anyway.

```
   \renewcommand{\flhead}[1]{\texttransparent{0.4} %Background Transparency
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node  at (3.18,-4.64) {
       \includegraphics[width=63.47mm, height=92.477mm]{pics/parch4.jpg}
    };%
\end{tikzpicture}}
   {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill[{#1}, even odd rule]

(-0.138,-9.24) rectangle ++(63.47mm,92.477mm)
(-0.138 + 0.175,-9.24+0.175) rectangle ++(60mm,89mm);
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

The command `\flhead` works, but only alone. Within the `\card` macro it does not work.

```
\card{
\flhead{black}
 \fchead{Test}\\
Test}{test}
```

Why this doesn't work? Any idea how it could work? This is for a present for my little brother and I want to finish this in the next 10 days.

P.S.: If you wonder why I made the frame in such a complicated way, I later want to apply some structure to the inner rectangle. (But this would be a new question)

Answer (score 1):

Here I set up a macro `\myflhead`, that redefines `\flhead` with the given color argument.  I think the issue is that, perhaps, `\flhead` is not intended, itself, to take arguments.

Still, `\myflhead` needs to be invoked prior to the invocation of `\card`, but can be used to change the border color.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,frontgrid]{flacards}
\usepackage{aurical}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,shadows,decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shapes.geometric,patterns}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\fboxsep=0mm


\renewcommand{\frfoot}{\footnotesize\thecardno\hskip3pt\smallskip} % change layout for left foot on front
\renewcommand{\brfoot}{}



%Group Colors

\definecolor{griff}{RGB}{224, 57, 35}
\definecolor{slyth}{RGB}{45, 205, 109}


%Command for Card Title:
\renewcommand{\fchead}[1]{\textbf{\Huge{#1}}}


%BACKGROUND

\newcommand\myflhead[1]{%
\renewcommand{\flhead}{\texttransparent{0.4} %Background Transparency
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node  at (3.18,-4.64) {
   \includegraphics[width=63.47mm, height=92.477mm]{example-image}
};%
\end{tikzpicture}}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill[{#1}, even odd rule]

(-0.138,-9.24) rectangle ++(63.47mm,92.477mm)
(-0.138 + 0.175,-9.24+0.175) rectangle ++(60mm,89mm);
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
}
\begin{document}

\Fontskrivan
\pagesetup{3}{3} % 3x3 cards

\myflhead{red}
\card{
\fchead{Test}\\
Test}{Empty}

\myflhead{green}
\card{
\fchead{Test}\\
Test}{Empty}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, to achieve the same result, `\card` could be redefined to take the border color as an optional argument, as in

```
\card[red]{
\fchead{Test}\\
Test}{Empty}
```

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,frontgrid]{flacards}
\usepackage{aurical}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,shadows,decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shapes.geometric,patterns}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\fboxsep=0mm


\renewcommand{\frfoot}{\footnotesize\thecardno\hskip3pt\smallskip} % change layout for left foot on front
\renewcommand{\brfoot}{}



%Group Colors

\definecolor{griff}{RGB}{224, 57, 35}
\definecolor{slyth}{RGB}{45, 205, 109}


%Command for Card Title:
\renewcommand{\fchead}[1]{\textbf{\Huge{#1}}}


%BACKGROUND

\newcommand\myflhead[1]{%
\renewcommand{\flhead}{\texttransparent{0.4} %Background Transparency
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node  at (3.18,-4.64) {
   \includegraphics[width=63.47mm, height=92.477mm]{example-image}
};%
\end{tikzpicture}}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill[{#1}, even odd rule]

(-0.138,-9.24) rectangle ++(63.47mm,92.477mm)
(-0.138 + 0.175,-9.24+0.175) rectangle ++(60mm,89mm);
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
}

\let\svcard\card
\renewcommand\card[2][black]{\myflhead{#1}\svcard{#2}}
\begin{document}

\Fontskrivan
\pagesetup{3}{3} % 3x3 cards

\card[red]{
\fchead{Test}\\
Test}{Empty}

\card[green]{
\fchead{Test}\\
Test}{Empty}

\end{document}
```