# Produce cards with a PNG background for each card

Tags: graphics, templates, document-classes, png

I need to produce 50 playing cards (60x90mm) with a template available in PSD or PNG or anything else (see picture below).

Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[paperheight=6cm,paperwidth=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\card}{
\centerline{\includegraphics{background.png}} % Why isn't it locked on top-left corner 
                                              % of the  page ? (it should)
% How to insert the text here, vertically + horizontally centered over the background?
\newpage
}

\begin{document}
\card{This is card 1.}
\card{Hello mister polynomial $x^2+1$.}

\end{document}
```

### Questions:

1. What file format to use for the background template? Would you use PNG? (Goal: I'm producing a PDF that will go to the print worker.)
2. Why doesn't the previous solution overwrite the text over the background? (this is what should happen)?

[image]

---

Bad output (with previous code):

[image]

Comment: `png` is a pixel format, at that limited size of your card however you won't see much issues from pixel.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've included a non-working example, do you see what's wrong?

Comment: Is this alternative relevant?? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354342/flacards-package-renewcommand-with-variables

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I modified the question to be more specific and to show where my current code fails.

Comment: maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207929/how-to-draw-the-cards-of-a-deck could be of interests

Comment: @samcarter and StevenBSegletes I'd like to do it without any 3rd party package. Now the only problems I'm facing (see my code) are: 1) how to have the PNG inserted on top-left corner (no margin)  2) how to make the text `\card{this is the text}` displayed centered horizontally / vertically over the background png.

Answer (score 11):

**Update at the end -- give it a try**

The background image can be done with `tcolorbox` and using many of its options, putting it in the background. See the applications of the options how the image is changed.

Considering the dimensions: Please take into account the cutting by your printer, so the margins should be larger, most likely!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=50mm,paperheight=90mm,margin=0pt,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{cardbox}[1][]{enhanced,nobeforeafter,after={\clearpage},width=50mm,height=90mm,halign=center, valign=center, title={This is card \thetcbcounter},colback={white!70!yellow},colbacktitle={cyan},coltitle={black},overlay={%
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
    \node[opacity=0.2] (A) at (interior.center) {\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=9cm]{ente}};
    \end{tcbclipinterior}
  },#1}

\parindent=0pt

\newcommand{\card}[2][]{%
  \begin{cardbox}[#1]
    #2%
  \end{cardbox}%
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\card{Hello Darkness my old friend}

\card[fontupper=\huge]{Hello Mr. Polynomial $x^{2} + x = 1$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=150mm,paperheight=270mm,margin=0pt,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}



\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{cardsboxstyle/.style={%
    left skip=0em,
    right skip=0em,
    width=50mm,
    height=90mm,
    halign=center, 
    valign=center,
    title={This is card \thetcbcounter},
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    colback={white!70!yellow},
    colbacktitle={cyan},
    coltitle={black}
  },
  backgroundimage/.style={%
    overlay={%
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
    \node[opacity=0.1] (A) at (interior.center) {\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=9cm]{ente}};
    \end{tcbclipinterior}
    }
  }
}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{cardbox}[1][]{enhanced,nobeforeafter,cardsboxstyle,backgroundimage,#1}

\parindent=0em

\newcommand{\card}[2][]{%
  \begin{cardbox}[#1]
    #2%
  \end{cardbox}%
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,raster column skip=0pt,raster row skip=0pt,raster width=150mm,raster equal height,raster left skip=0pt,raster right skip=0pt]
\card{Hello Duckness my old friend}
\card[fontupper=\huge]{Hello Mr. Polynomial $x^{2} + x = 1$}
\card{Hello Cuteness my old friend}
\card[colbacktitle={red},overlay={\draw[opacity=0.2,step=1cm,help lines,blue] (interior.north east) grid (interior.south west);}]{Hello Cuteness my old friend}
\card{Hello Duckness my old friend}
\card[fontupper=\huge]{Hello Mr. Polynomial $x^{2} + x = 1$}
\card{Hello Cuteness my old friend}
\card{Hello Duckness my old friend}
\card[colupper={blue},ams align]{E=mc^{2}}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oooooooooh `:)`

Comment: This is upvote pleading `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: No, it is just lazyness ... it's my standard image to be included

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this??

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[paperheight=6cm,paperwidth=9cm,margin=.1pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\newcommand{\card}[1]{\def\stacktype{L}%
\stackon[-.35\paperheight]{%
\raisebox{-.94\paperheight}{\includegraphics[width=1\paperwidth,height=.2\paperheight]{%
  example-image}}%
}{\Centerstack{#1}}%
\newpage%
}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
\card{hello}
\card{hello2\\this is a test\\of my method}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**FOLLOW UP** (to answer OP's question below)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[paperheight=6cm,paperwidth=9cm,margin=.1pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\newcommand{\card}[1]{\def\stacktype{L}%
\stackon[-.45\paperheight]{%
\raisebox{-.94\paperheight}{\includegraphics[width=1\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{%
  example-image}}%
}{\Centerstack{#1}}%
\newpage%
}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
\card{hello}
\card{hello2\\this is a test\\of my method}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `.94\paperheight` image shift is, essentially, `\dimexpr-\paperheight+\baselineskip\relax`

**P.S.**

The following code can supercede both of the above examples, allowing the image height to be independently specified in the `\def` of `\imgheight`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[paperheight=6cm,paperwidth=9cm,margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\def\imgheight{1.0\paperheight}% <---THIS SETS HOW MUCH OF THE CARD THE IMAGE TAKES UP
\newcommand{\card}[1]{\def\stacktype{L}%
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\paperheight+.85\baselineskip\relax}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{\dimexpr.5\paperheight-.5\dimexpr\imgheight\relax}{%
  \Centerstack{#1}}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\imgheight]{example-image}}%
}%
\newpage%
}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
\card{hello}
\card{hello2\\this is a test\\of my method}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Steven! The only little remaining thing is that the image should take the whole 6x9cm space, and the text should be *over* (on top) of the image.

Comment: @Basj See **FOLLOW UP**

Comment: Thanks a lot @StevenBSegletes, it works. Last question: would you see a version without any 3rd party packages? (Just for LaTeX learning purposes).  This works for the vertical+horizontal centering : `\newcommand{\card}[1]{
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
#1
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage
}` but how to insert the PNG image as background? Is there a way to move the cursor at the top of the page to do then `\centerline{\includegraphics{background.png}}` ?

Comment: @Basj Well, since I wrote `stackengine`, does that make it a 1st-party package?? `:^)` I figure you already have `geometry` and `graphic`...

Comment: Haha right ;) I was trying with this (rput), but it doesn't work: `\newcommand{\card}[1]{
\rput(0,0){\includegraphics{background.png}}
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
#1
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage`. The vertical/horiz alignement of text works, the image is displayed, but unfortunately not at the top left corner...

Comment: @Basj Maybe try a `\noindent` before invoking `\card`.

Comment: This seems to work now: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355272/27733

Answer (score 4):

An `eso-pic` solution:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[paperheight=6cm,paperwidth=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\includegraphics[height=6cm,width=9cm]{example-grid-100x100bp}}

\newcommand{\card}[1]{%
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}%
\centering%
#1
\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\color{white}
\card{test}%
\card{bla}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By combining what I've learned thanks to the good answers here and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156914/27733) about image background, this finally works (without any 3rd-party package):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[paperheight=6cm,paperwidth=9cm,margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\card}[1]{
\noindent
\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-\totalheight}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics{background.png}}}
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}#1\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage
}

\begin{document}
\card{This is card 3.}
\card{Hello mister polynomial $x^2+1$\\You too}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If anyone sees even simpler than makebox, raisebox, topskip, I'm interested to learn an even more simple solution!